# how do you handle input sanitization on forms?

Tags: security

how do you handle input sanitization on forms?  do you use javascrpt or just client?

Answer (score 1):

Client-size (javascript) sanitization doesn't protect you from anything. It's super-easy to bypass it (you can easily do it in firebug or any other web dev toolset).

So server-side sanitization and validation is always an absolute must.

Comment: so i should do both right?  if we're doing it on server, do we still want to have on client?

Comment: Yes both that way you stop round trips to and from the server if the user doesn't fill in the form correctly.

Comment: Yes, ideally you should make both, it's just much quicker for user to get an instant response from JS, however every validation and sanitization you add in JS must be implemented server-side. I can't stress enough just how important it is, and how often people make a fatal mistake of sanitizing content client-side and not doing it on a server. You do stuff client-side for comfort, you do things server-side for security.